# Recursive C Function - Print Ascending Order

Tags: c, loops, recursion

I'm trying to implement a code that recursively calls itself and prints the given digits in ascending order, i.e. if the number is 5, then the function will print 1 2 3 4 5. I cannot use loops in any way!

```
void print_ascending(int n)
{
   int i = 1;

   if(i < n)
   {
      printf("%d", i);

      i++;

      print_ascending(n);
   }
}
```

Of course, the problem with this code is it will re-initialize the variable i to 1 every single time and infinitely loop to print 1.

There are also no outside global variables or outside functions allowed!

Comment: see what `static` does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try incrementing value of argument, when you call recursive function each time.

```
void print_ascending(int limit, int current_value)
{
   if(current_value < limt)
   {
     printf("%d ", current_value);
     print_ascending(limit, current_value + 1);
   }
}
```

Initially call the function as
`print_ascending(5, 1)`

Alternatively,

```
void print_ascending(int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        print_ascending( n - 1);
        printf("%d ", n); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function can be defined simply the following way

```
void print_ascending( unsigned int n )
{

    if ( n > 1 ) print_ascending( n - 1 ); 
    printf( "%u ", n );
}
```

I used type `unsigned int` instead of `int` because otherwise you have to consider the case when n can be a negative number.